# Cannot open ActiveMQ Admin page after starting the server?

Tags: macos, jms, activemq-classic

I'm not sure if I started the server or not. But, I cannot open the admin page on the browser.

[image]

Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you should generally always do is check the broker log and see if there's an error.  Also running the broker in foreground after you alter the configuration will show you any errors that might be there you can run:

```
   ./bin/activemq console
```

To run in foreground mode.

Beyond that its hard to help since you haven't provided information like you configuration or done a 'ps -ef | grep activemq' etc.

Answer (score 1):

check your `/conf/activemq.xml` file and make sure `<import resource="jetty.xml"/>` is included